# Making a java web application as the root of a domain name in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm currently developing a Java web application *myapp* and when deployed in Tomcat 6 server, I access *myapp* with this URL: `http://localhost:8080/myapp`

Instead I want to access my application using this URL: `http://myapp:8080` since *myapp* will be the only application deployed in my Tomcat 6.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in Tomcat in basically two ways:

1. Set `path` attribute of `<Context>` element in `Webapp/META-INF/context.xml` (or `Tomcat/conf/server.xml`, depending where you'd like to define it) to an empty String. E.g.

   ```
   <Context path="">
   ```
2. Rename it to `ROOT.war` and Tomcat will automagically deploy it as ROOT.

Outside Tomcat there are more ways to do this, such as (virtual) proxy, URL rewriting with `.htaccess`, etcetera.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you meen you want your url to be http://localhost:8080 not http://myapp:8080.

If you dont need the default apps that come with tomcat then just go to your webapps directory (where myapp is probably located) and look for another folder called ROOT (in my Tomcat 6).  rename ROOT to something else and rename myapp to ROOT.  This is a quick and messy way that works because the default host's appBase is webapps and the default app is ROOT.

If you had access to the tomcat/conf/ directory then you could edit the server.xml file but Im not very knowledgeable about server.xml so I wont try and walk you through it.